# При наведении на ссылки, другие блоки съезжают на величину добавленных паддингов для бэкграунда ссылки

Tags: html, css

Пример:

```css
.dashboard__card__1__nav {
  display: flex;
  padding-left: 7px;
  margin-top: 71px;
  margin-bottom: 24px;
}

.dashboard__card__1__nav a {
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 133%;
  color: #666666;
}

.dashboard__card__1__nav a:hover {
  padding: 7px 11px;
  background: #2A2A2A;
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.043);
  border-radius: 4px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}

.dashboard__card__1__nav li:not(:first-child) {
  margin: 0px 16px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="dashboard__card__1__nav">
  <li>
    <a href="">File previews</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="">Column view</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="">List view</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="">Multi select actions</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="">Path navigator</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Скрин:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это можно решить, если `padding: 7px 11px;` задать для класса `.dashboard__card__1__nav a`.

А из класса `.dashboard__card__1__nav a:hover` наоборот убрать `padding: 7px 11px;`

Ваш пример:

```css
.dashboard__card__1__nav {
  display: flex;
  padding-left: 7px;
  margin-top: 71px;
  margin-bottom: 24px;
}

.dashboard__card__1__nav a {
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 133%;
  color: #666666;
  padding: 7px 11px;
}

.dashboard__card__1__nav a:hover {
  
  background: #2A2A2A;
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.043);
  border-radius: 4px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}

.dashboard__card__1__nav li:not(:first-child) {
  margin: 0px 16px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="dashboard__card__1__nav">
  <li>
    <a href="">File previews</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="">Column view</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="">List view</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="">Multi select actions</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="">Path navigator</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```